What is the name of a chart in which bars are concatenated?
What is the name of the chart in which bars are concatenated?, for example:
I try to show the following sequence of loss and gain
10-2+3-5
first step in x-axis
increase in y-axis up to 10 and set a point
second step ahead in x-axis
decrease the last point in 2 units
third step ahead in x-axis
increase the last point in 3 units
and so on

do you mean stacked bars? If not, can you provide a graphic example?

Maybe you mean a waterfall chart?

Based on your description you may mean waterfall chart.

A waterfall chart is a form of data visualization that helps in understanding the cumulative effect of sequentially introduced positive or negative values. These intermediate values can either be time based or category based. The waterfall chart is also known as a flying bricks chart or Mario chart due to the apparent suspension of columns (bricks) in mid-air. Often in finance, it will be referred to as a bridge.


